# PHP retry PDO execute if Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock

Tags: php

I have 2 PHP applications inserting/updating the same table which is causing deadlocks. The first application will occur every 2 minutes and scans for new files to insert/update and does an OCR process that later updates another table which I assume is causing the deadlock since this process can take the longest. The second application is moving archive data into the same table, with over several million records, 8+ and counting. I've read an option around this would be to write a retry loop for 3 times. However, I don't think it's working. Here is my code below. I'm also open to other suggestions as well.

```
$retry=0;
$notdone=TRUE;
while ($notdone && $retry<3){
    try{
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($qry);
     $stmt->execute($dataArray);
     $notdone=FALSE;
    }catch(Exception $e){
     $retry++;
     $log->trace("Retry count at $retry, delay 5 seconds before executing");
     sleep(5);
    }
}
if($retry == 3) {
    $retVal['error'] = "Statement 1 Error: could not connect to database: ".$e->getMessage();
    $log->trace($retVal['error']);
}
```

Comment: When you say you don't think it is working what is the result you're getting when it runs?

Comment: I only get the log for the PDO deadlock but not the the Retry count

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem was due to the wrong exception being used, once I used PDOexception I started it started the retry correctly.